# .Net: What should be the approach to capture video from multiple cameras to flv

Tags: c#, .net, flv, webcam, video-capture

I want to create an application which will take the web cam as an input
 and save the captured video as an flv file.

I am looking at Adobe's Flash Live Media Encoder for the same but it doesn't have an API but has a command line tool for the encoding.

Please suggest some other alternatives i could look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at OpenCV (http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) and VLC (http://www.videolan.org/vlc/).

UPDATE: I'm using this port of OpenCV for C# http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/OpenCV